# Update document fields of word using OfficeJS

Tags: office-js

In VSTO, we can easily update fields of a word document using c# code:

```
 _wordApplication.ActiveDocument.Fields.Update();
```

Is there any way to do same job in OfficeJS?  I am using OfficeJS 1.4 beta version.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

good question!
Not now, we do support custom doc properties and xmlParts so depending on your scenario you might be ok,  but Fields is something we are planning to support in the future. Don't forget to vote for this on our user voice channel, there is an existing item tracking doc fields support.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/163566-add-in-word

thanks.

Comment: how "custom doc properties and xmlParts" can solve my scenario? any clue ? @Juan Balmori

Comment: I don't know your scenario, but if you can share more details I might be able to help. For instance, what are you using fields for?

Comment: Actually I am merging multiple document to a document and opening that document programmitcally. In every document I have a field "seq" for numbering. Now, while adding all document into I one I need to update the seq filed so that numbering shows correctly. Currently, all the number is showing 1. While developing with VSTO, I just added all the document into one and updated the field. It was showing the proper numbering after open like I have 3 document merged into one, and it showing 1,2,3 on each document.

Comment: Juan Balmori, Is there any update on interacting with Field codes using the Word Javascript Api?